# Feynman rules for scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, interactions

Can i have a derivation for the Feynman rules of scalar QED?
I don't understand the ones i find online such as the one in the link https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/936391/download?download_frd=1&verifier=x0zyaPHMxOvHCcrRCDqlHUqjT4stQ3tv0Z69Eohc , it just seems too abstract, something that misses lots of steps or explain them away in words, isnt there a more algebric way of doing it? One that would generalize to other theories a well? Like, i dont know, substituting the expression of the fields up there as the Fourier expansion in momentum into the interacting piece of the lagrangian, can i please see how this would work out (if it would work)? I dont know how to deal with the A miu

Comment: Have you understood how to derive the Feynman rules for any other quantum field theory yet? Or are you starting with scalar QED?

Comment: i am studying quantum field theory and they gave me the feynman rules in the lectures also for other theories, but i never understood how they calculate them, for scalar QED they basically have the above explanation from the pdf, i know how to compute feynman diagrams from perturbative expansion, so i did the basic feynman rules for phi^3 theory

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

Vector fields are tedious to write, so I will use Yukawa theory.

Step1:

Perturbation expansion:
$$Z[j,h]=\int D\phi D\varphi\  e^{iS_0+iS_I+\int_x(j\phi+h\varphi)}=\int D\phi D\varphi\  \Big(\sum_n\frac{(iS_I[\phi,\varphi])^n}{n!}\Big)e^{iS_0+\int_x(j\phi+h\varphi)},$$
$$S_0=\int_x\Big\{\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi\partial\phi-m^2\phi^2)+\frac{1}{2}(\partial\varphi\partial\varphi-m^2\varphi^2)\Big\}$$
$$S_I=\int_x\Big\{\frac{g}{2}\varphi\phi\phi\Big\}.$$

Step2:

Perform the path integral
$$Z[j,h]=\Big(\sum_n\frac{(iS_I[\frac{\delta}{i\delta j},\frac{\delta}{i\delta h}])^n}{n!}\Big)\int D\phi D\varphi\ e^{iS_0+\int_x(j\phi+h\varphi)}$$
$$=\Big(\sum_n\frac{(iS_I[\frac{\delta}{i\delta j},\frac{\delta}{i\delta h}])^n}{n!}\Big)\ e^{-\int_{x,y}j_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}j_y}e^{-\int_{x,y}h_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}h_y}.$$

The exact form of $S_I$ is

$$S_I=\int_x\Big\{\frac{g}{2} \frac{\delta}{i\delta j}\Big(\frac{\delta}{i\delta h}\Big)^2\Big\}.$$

Substituting this expression, we will conclude

$$Z[j,h]= \sum_n (ig)^n\Big(\frac{1}{n!\ 2^n}\Big)\Big(\Big\{\int_x \frac{\delta}{i\delta j}(\frac{\delta}{i\delta h}\Big)^2\Big\}^n\ e^{-\int_{x,y}j_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}j_y}e^{-\int_{x,y}h_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}h_y}\Big).$$

One can read the Feynman rule from this expression. The terms in the first parenthesis give the Feynman rules for coupling constant, and the terms in the third parenthesis give the propagators. Also,the terms in the second parenthesis are simple numerical factors called as a symmetry factor.

Note that each functional derivative about $h$ or $j$ produce the delta functions, and they cancels most of $\int_x$s in the third parenthesis and from the exponential, but sometimes some of these integrals can not be canceled by delta functions. This is the loop integral, and related to the topology of diagrams.

From this basic equation for partition function, you can derive the Feynman rules for n-point function. For example, if we are interested in $\langle\phi\phi\varphi\varphi\rangle$, it is given by

$$\langle\phi_u\phi_v\varphi_z\varphi_w\rangle\sim \frac{\delta}{i\delta j_u} \frac{\delta}{i\delta j_v}\frac{\delta}{i\delta h_z}\frac{\delta}{i\delta h_w} Z[j,h] $$
$$= \sum_n (ig)^n\Big(\frac{1}{n!\ 2^n}\Big)\Big(\Big\{\int_\tilde{x} \frac{\delta}{i\delta j _\tilde{x}}(\frac{\delta}{i\delta h_\tilde{x}}\Big)^2\Big\}^n $$
$$\times \frac{\delta}{i\delta j_u} \frac{\delta}{i\delta j_v}\frac{\delta}{i\delta h_z}\frac{\delta}{i\delta h_w}  e^{-\int_{x,y}j_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}j_y}e^{-\int_{x,y}h_x(\Box+m^2)^{-1}h_y}\Big). $$

Extensions to momentum space, QED, etc. are not so difficult if one follows the above and starts from the partition function.

Comment: This just not a good explanation for someone who's already struggling with the standard textbook derivation. The sheet they reference doesn't even use the path integral approach.